# How can I get rid of Windows Update reboot prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-update

I want Windows Update to automatically download and install updates on my Vista machine, however I don't want to be bothered by the system tray reboot prompts (which can, at best, only be postponed by 4 hours).

I have performed the registry hack described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/prevent-windows-update-from-forcibly-rebooting-your-computer/) to prevent Windows forcibly rebooting my machine, which is a good start. However, is there any way to get rid of the reboot prompts altogether, or decrease their frequency?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure if it is the same for vista, but worth a try.

On Windows XP, you can modify a group policy setting to change how frequently it re-prompts you. (start -> run type gpedit.msc)

Look under Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Update

The setting you want is called Re-Prompt for restart with scheduled installations. 
The default is 10 minutes.

You can also try modifying the No auto-restart for scheduled Automatic Updates installations setting found in the same location.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me too. Interestingly, despite already using the NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers registry hack, the "No auto-restart for scheduled Automatic Updates installations" was still set to "Not configured". Do these do the same thing?

Comment: I'm guessing that they do exactly the same thing. In my experience, generally, you can either change the registry directly, or use group policy and get the same results. I suspect that simply changing the registry does not update some meta data for the group policy editor somewhere.

Comment: Group Policy is generally stored under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Company\Product. If an application supports group policy, it uses these keys to override the values stored under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Company\Product.

Answer (score 3):

Just turn off the Automatic Update service. It will restart the next time you reboot so you'll still get the updates done.

Answer (score 3):

Running this in a command window will stop it until the next reboot.

```
 sc stop wuauserv
```

Comment: True, but mildly tedious to have to do this every time. I'm looking for something I can set and forget.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend disabling the auto update.

As a developer the last thing you need is to have random updates done to your workstation, especially while you are working.   I set aside a time every month to go through the process manually.  I avoid doing it if I am in the middle of testing something really important or up against an immediate deadline.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify what [ehogue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137/ehogue) said:
Start->Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services->Automatic Updates->Right-click->Stop.

Comment: You can also do Start->Run and type services.msc to get to the services and stop it.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows XP, after windows has been updated, I use the following trick: run this command

```
pssuspend wuauclt
```

[pssuspend](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540.aspx) is a free sys-internals tool.

This way, you will not be prompted about restart.

Answer (score 0):

I will risk some down-votes here by saying: this seems a little bit schizophrenic, though a lot of people ask for it.

If you want Windows to download and install the updates, but **not** complete the install process by rebooting - what's the point? Why not simply turn of AutoUpdates in the first place? if you don't even want the OS to tell you it would like to reboot, then how can you know that you need to, y'know, reboot?

Patches which call for a reboot **are not fully active until that reboot is complete**; thus your system remains vulnerable to the unpatched behaviour. If you are a human who goes to the bathroom or eats meals, I just do not understand the mentality of wanting to patch but then postpone the reboot for days, weeks, months. Better to stay unpatched!

Comment: Your point is not unreasonable. However, I always shut down my home PC when I'm not using it, so it's getting rebooted a lot anyway (admittedly this is not true for my office PC). This way I can be sure I'm keeping up to date with updates, without having them interrupt what I'm doing.

Comment: You are clearly better off with patches downloaded and not installed than with updates disabled, as at least they will be installed eventually.

The UI interrupting your work is an unforgiveable sin and this includes flashing titlebars, flashing notifications in the system tray or stealing focus within 1 second of a key press.

Answer (score 0):

just open taskmanager and right-click on "wuauclt.exe" en clcik stop or delete or something that should keep that program from running.